# How to save a object notation path in to a variable to use in template?

Tags: typescript, angular5, mustache

I need to fetch the data from a long path. so i trying to store the path in a variable and decided to add in the template. but not works.

any one help me here?

here is my try:

My stored path : `propBasePath:string =` `${header.label.lacales}`

when I console like this:

```
this.appProps = value;

console.log( this.appProps[this.propBasePath]['th_TH'] ) //this is not works!!
console.log( this.appProps.header.label.lacales.th_TH ) it's works.
```

In template:

```
<h1 style="font-size: 3rem">{{appProps[propBasePath].th_TH}}</h1>
```

as well the above not works. I know that the way I am trying to retrieve the data is wrong. But any one correct me please?

I am getting this error as well `ERROR ReferenceError: header is not defined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, you can't do that this way. You can't find a property from an object by passing the path as `myObject['prop1.prop2.prop3']` because it will try to find the property `prop1.prop2.prop3` itself.

In order to solve your issue, you can do something like 
the following example to get each property before diving into the result and get the next property until you get the one you are looking for.

```js
const obj = {
  prop1: {
    prop2: {
        prop3: 'The value you are looking for'
    }
  }
};

const myPath = 'prop1.prop2.prop3';
const deepValue = myPath.split('.').reduce((obj, current) => obj[current], obj);
console.log(deepValue);
```

I hope this example will help you :)